# Need ideas for using axios when running html file locally (e.g. file:// path in browser)

Tags: javascript

The goal is to have a .html file that can be opened directly (e.g. run as file://path-to-file.../file.html in Chrome browser).

Their is a /user-json folder, where users can drop in their own .json files and the .html file loads up the json data.

I am currently using axios to a) find all files in that /user-json directory, and then b) load them in for use in the javascript.

The issue is that CORS/Browsers blocks these axios requests due to security policies.

A work around is to use --allow-file-access-from-files, but I want to provide an easy way for anyone to just drop-in their own "user-json" data into that /user-json folder, and have the .html detect and load it up, without needing to play around with their chrome browser settings or even running a web server.

Any ideas for getting this to work or alternative methods? Please don't suggest running the files on a server as I'm away of that option - I'm looking for a way users can provide their own files that the locally opened .html file can detect and load in.

Comment: You sacrifice a lot of capabilities, including that one, by opening the page from a `file:` url. Consider that if a page without security can just open any file, the page could also transmit any file somewhere.

Comment: I understand why there are security measures in place, but want I'm asking is for an approach to loading content for locally opened html - purely so that it does not need to be accessed through a http protocol or similar

Comment: And, as you've discovered, the answer is no, due to security.

Comment: Yep. My solution here is to use javascript files that are 'expected' as a way of adding in user-added data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can go about this. It's mostly a matter of picking your favourite abstraction.

Easiest would be to leverage a service like [CORS Anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/). Though of course that isn't the most robust solution, and if you're concerned with the aesthetics of your code, it likely won't appeal (note: there is an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere)).

Alternatively, if you want to host your own solution, you can spin up a free instance, like a [Cloudflare Worker](https://workers.cloudflare.com/); they even have an example of how to accomplish what you're after [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/cors-header-proxy).

Passing your requests through nginx is also possible, and arguably much more succinct and performant.

Any way you go about it, you'll have to route your requests through some kind of proxy, because a stock Chrome browser is not gonna cut it.

Bon voyage.

Comment: I don't believe CORS Anywhere would work if the file was opened locally - still seems to require http protocol or similar.

I don't want to host a solution, no, as this is not that type of project - it is meant to be opened after receiving locally on your machine.

I realise loading with axios isn't going to work for what I want to accomplish, but then will other approaches be possible? Since we cannot make requests, what if there were simply pre-compiled JS files that are opened? I think that might be the only way I can think of and even then I need to test how this works in this use-case

Comment: Lacking more context, it's challenging for me to spitball with you more. I know chrome extensions offer an API to access the local file system but that's only for file paths you predefine because you know them ahead of time; you're also scoped to the extension's root directory.. All said, there are some extremely ambitious and comprehensive extensions out there. Really, though, it sounds like a job that's meant for a tool that lives closer to the filesystem than the browser. Electron?

Comment: Indeed electron! I wanted to steer clear of this if possible but I'm now leaning in that direction. This is purely for portability reasons - downloading a html file to your mobile can be run quite easily. No need to "install" apps or anything.

One idea I have is to: a) create a "user-addon-1.js" file and "user-addon-2.js" file. b) user uses my app to create the "user-addon-1.js" file and replaces it and c) have the html file already try to load "user-addon-1.js" and "user-addon-2.js" and so on...

It's a bit ugly, but should work I believe